# How to implement custom 'like' clause in NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm, pervasive

I started to use NHibernate together with Pervasive SQL engine - all in all it works fine though this is something I cannot overcome. I've implemented my own Dialect and Driver. The problem is that I cannot specify the 'like' behaviour for this type of db engine.

The specification says that basically I cannot put concatenation after like clause - I did checked it - Pervasive throws an error (`('%'||?||'%')` pseudo-code is generated from within NHibernate).

The question is - is it possible to change the default behaviour of NHibernate engine so it doesn't concat the strings but just inserts it inside after like clause?

So instead of `'%'||?||'%'` I would get `'%search_term%'`. Oh, and btw. I'm using linq provider for querying NHb.

Answer (score 0):

look at this example:

```
     customers = session.CreateQuery("FROM Customer c WHERE c.AccountNumber LIKE :accNumber")
    .SetString("accNumber", "%" + accountNumber + "%")
    .SetMaxResults(size)
    .List<Customer>();
```

hope this helps

Comment: Yes, I've found that sample too. I'd prefer using LINQ but since I can't find any sample for my case I'll have to stick to this solution for now. Thx.

Comment: if you strictly wanted to use LINQ, you might try this one too: .Where(x => x.SomeProperty.Contains("whaetever"))

Comment: Yes, I know. But the problem is that LINQ provider for NHb generates wrong query - Pervasive SQL engine does not allow string concatenation after like-clause and this is default bahaviour for NHb.